# Make pycharm use the real ipython console

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm

In pycharm, the ipython console does not seem to be a real ipython console.

In pycharm ipython console:

```
In[1]: ?sorted
{'text/plain': 'Signature: sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=False)\nDocstring:\nReturn a ne
```

In a real ipython console:

```
In [5]: ?sorted
Signature: sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=False)
Docstring:
Return a new list containing all items from the iterable in ascending order.

A custom key function can be supplied to customise the sort order, and the
reverse flag can be set to request the result in descending order.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

I saw some other differences: `does not load ipython profile`, `different behavior when using shortcut to get back previous commands`

Is there anyway to have a real ipython console in pycharm? And that this console is still compatible with the shortcuts to run the selected code in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that you're using different virtual environments/python versions in PyCharm and locally? That could perfectly explain differences in the outputs.

Can you run this code in both and compare the output:

```
import IPython; IPython.version_info
```

---

EDIT

Confirmed, PyCharm converts the output of the `ipython` even if the versions are the same.

Comment: In pycharm, I get this: `import IPython; IPython.version_info
Out[13]: (6, 1, 0, '')`, in ipython , I get the same....