# PyCharm python console - ipython magic output

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm

I have started recently to use PyCharm for some python development under Win10. I am still struggling to find the best configuration with consoles.

I have ipython enabled in the built-in PyCharm console, but it does not always work like a normal ipython. The most annoying feature is that the output of the pinfo/? magic does not display properly:

```
In[1]: a=123
In[2]: ?a
{'text/plain': "Type:        int\nString form: 123\nDocstring:  \nint(x=0)[...]
```

In a normal ipython console I get, as expected,

```
In [1]: a=123

In [2]: a?
Type:        int
String form: 123
Docstring:
int(x=0) -> integer
[...]
```

Is there a way to change this behavior? Or a way to hook up PyCharm to an external console running in e.g. ConEmu?

I am using PyCharm 2017.1.4, python 3.5.3, PyCharm invokes there ipython 5.3.0.

Comment: From my experience built-in console in PyCharm won't work with this, it has some limitations. One of them is not supporting Carriage Return (CR) which is used to modify already printed line.

Comment: What about using a terminal (Alt+F12) and starting `ipython` from within the terminal? Your virtual environment should be on the path then and you will be using the native iPython interpreter. @Artur I think the problem is rather that iPython provides a JSON object while PyCharm simply prints whatever it gets back (probably assuming it is a string). In the [iPython docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/development/messaging.html#payloads) they speak about this kind of payloads being deprecated anyway however not yet replaced.

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44388352/make-pycharm-use-the-real-ipython-console) (can't mark as duplicate, as no accepted answer was given).